# Disappearing a sprite during boundary collision in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I have a rectangular group that holds a bunch of sprites. Sprites are moving (say up). As they reach the top, they collide with the boundary. I have set up logic that kills the sprites as they exit the group. However, the way it is now, I can see the sprite leaving the group. I want to make it so that as the sprite is crossing the boundary, it's gradually disappearing until it's out (and dead).

Here's a crude mockup of what I want to achieve.

[image: collision]

I was playing around with cameras thinking I have to modify the viewport, but it's not working. What's the proper way of achieving this effect?

Thanks!

EDIT:
My camera was set up like this:

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    camera.position.set(width/2, height/2, 0);
```

Right now it's operating from the group's parent level (layer). Width and height are Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), etc.
My update():

```
    camera.position.x = (width / 2) - resolver.getxPixelOffset()*parallax;
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    g.drawGroup(batch);
    batch.end();
```

I moved my camera controls to my group class. I then changed the width and height to groupWidth and groupHeight. Since the group is not the entire screen, I figured it has to be smaller. This made the group massive. I don't want to change the size (or zoom?) of the group :(

Comment: Actually, setting the camera viewport should do the trick. Can you show us what did you try ?

Comment: I showed some code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself, but I believe the proper way of doing this would be using [scissors](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ScissorStack.html). Basically, the scissors allow you to clip a region out of your picture, and only allow things in that region to be drawn, so you would probably do something like similar to what they do in the demo [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping%2C-with-the-use-of-scissorstack):

```
Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle();
Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissors);
ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
spriteBatch.draw(...);
spriteBatch.flush();
ScissorStack.popScissors();
```

You may need to draw and flush your background image (if you have one) before you draw with the scissors.

Comment: Interesting! A question: it says "A stack of Rectangle objects to be used for clipping via GL20.glScissor(int, int, int, int)".
My config is GL10. Will it be compatible?

Comment: @VeryAttractiveS Dunno for certain, you may want to try this out yourself. However, since GL20 is the [default version now](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3311), you may want to consider upgrading your libgdx version, if possible.